# Does ADF provide feature to use 'dynamic' Linked Server?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there any way to create dynamic linked server? Generally we declare linked server and point it to some fixed resource (either compute or storage). What if,  based on the value of some variable in some form I want to be able to point to any resource dynamically. Its value won't have to be known in advance.

To provide an example, say I have N different HDInsight clusters and my pipelines should be able to point to any one of them based on some parameter(what parameter is not important here, as long as ADF has some scheme). And here while declaring linked server, I will simply specify the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dhiraj,
We want to add this capability shortly in ADF. It does not exist today apart from inside a custom activity in ADF.

Thanks, Harish